# Truncating file that has STDOUT being redirected to it

Tags: node.js, filesystems, stdout

I have a node application that is having it's STDOUT being redirected to a log file:

```
node app.js > /var/log/app.out
```

From inside my node program I want to reset the log in order to keep it from growing too large. I've attempted `fs.truncate` and `fs.open('/var/log/app.out', 'w')` in order to reset it's length, but when I try to verify the file size using `ls` or `stat`, the file size seems to quickly reset to 0, then reset to it's previous size plus new messages (I currently am forcing a lot of output).

```
root@ubuntu-1304-mike:/var/log# stat app.out
  File: ‘app.out’
  Size: 5885622     Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 270560      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-09-26 17:20:06.784564421 -0600
Modify: 2013-09-26 17:20:49.088565625 -0600
Change: 2013-09-26 17:20:49.088565625 -0600
 Birth: -
root@ubuntu-1304-mike:/var/log# stat app.out
  File: ‘app.out’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 270560      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-09-26 17:20:06.784564421 -0600
Modify: 2013-09-26 17:20:51.772565702 -0600
Change: 2013-09-26 17:20:51.772565702 -0600
 Birth: -
root@ubuntu-1304-mike:/var/log# stat app.out
  File: ‘app.out’
  Size: 6038458     Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 270560      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-09-26 17:20:06.784564421 -0600
Modify: 2013-09-26 17:20:53.640565755 -0600
Change: 2013-09-26 17:20:53.640565755 -0600
 Birth: -
```

It seems that STDOUT is re-writing it's buffer to the file (regardless of how large the buffer is).

How can I truncate a file that STDOUT is actively being redirected to, without breaking out of my node app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that STDOUT is re-writing it's buffer to the file (regardless of how large the buffer is).

Nobody is re-writing a buffer, it's already written on the disk. When application finishes writing something, it remembers position where it finished, and it starts with this position later. It's not a node issue, and there's nothing you can do about it, it's how unix pipes work (unless there's some ugly hack to rewind a pipe I don't know about).

> How can I truncate a file that STDOUT is actively being redirected to, without breaking out of my node app?

Don't use stdout redirection and write to a file instead. If you can't modify your app, write another app that uses more clever approach and redirect stdout to it like that: `node app.js | node write-stdin-to-app.out.js`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, as well. Using the append operator is the best way to solve it:

`node app.js >> /var/log/app.out`

Now you can truncate the file with `fs.truncate` or even:

`echo -n > /var/log/app.out`